# Sign a transaction programmatically with a bash command line command

Tags: private-key, signature

Let's suppose i have my metamask/ledger secret seed phrase.

Here is what i want to do:

- I want to calculate the first account private key
- I want to sign a message with this private key

It is possible to do that with some online services which works with metamask wallet. But i want to do this myself on my computer, with my program.

Are there some linux command line tools (like openssl) which can do this task ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The web3js, ether.ja libraries have methods to do that

Comment: It is not possible to do that with a bash command (like openssl ?)

Comment: I think yes because it is not magic only basic encryption, decryption and signing , but don’t know how. Better to change the title of the question or ask this exactly in a new question

Comment: Thanks, i've edited the title